# Screen Capture Methods for Broadcasting/Recording

Tags: directshow, record, capture, broadcast

From what I understand programs like xSplit use DirectShow Filters (VHScrCap) to capture the desktop or running applications (such as games)

Fraps I believe uses driver hooking in order to record the game footage.

My question is what are the benefits of each method?

In addition to that are there any game recording software that use directshow filters or broadcasting software that use driver hooking? If not why?

Answer (score 0):

With DirectShow you can capture video on external device such as camera, or substitute your presenter in order to make something stream into your code rather than to actual display device. None of these cover capturing the desktop and DirectShow has nothing to do with this.

Desktop capture takes place either by polling desktop (easy but inefficient) or providing mirror display driver, or by flavors of hooks. In any event the goal is to receive screen updates as early as possible, with best possible detail about the data being presented.

Comment: From what I've read on the splitmedia site, it says "(VHScrCap) is a DirectShow filter which emulates Video Capture card and captures screen activity." is this not capturing the desktop?

mirror display drivers are the most efficient way of polling the desktop, however this is just useful for GDI drawing and doesn't really work with directdraw or directx applications. I've also read that another problem with mirror drivers is that it doesn't support Aero in Vista or 7 and it is considered obsolete?

Comment: I am also trying to use DirectShow to record the screen (along with webcam, mic, and system audio) to make a screencast. @kiwijus did you figure ito ut? at roman DirectShow can do this I think right? btw thanks so much for your help i was able to record DirectShow with your tips (not system audio yet but i got mic)